# Javascript date toISOSstring/toJSON one day backwards

Tags: javascript, time

I store two dates. First date is the current day and the second one is a future date. To convert those dates into format year-month-day I use toISOSstring function. However usually (but not always) the current date is changed one day backwards.

I also tried to use toJSON function instead. But nothing has changed.

```
    season.from =  "Sun Apr 02 2017 18:29:52 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
    season.to =   "Fri Apr 21 2017 18:29:52 GMT+0200 (CEST)"

    var date1 = new Date(season.from);
    var date2 = new Date(season.to);

    season.from = date1.toISOString().slice(0,10);
    season.to = date2.toISOString().slice(0,10);
    console.log(season.from); // one day backwards (e.g. 2017-04-01 not 2017-04-02)
    console.log(season.to); // proper date somewhere in the future
```

Comment: please show sample input values as per [mcve]

Comment: I've updated my post with sample input (season.from and season.to).

Answer (score 0):

Your original time strings are in local time, or at least they have a time zone specification. But [`toISOString` returns the UTC time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

> The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z"

In the case of your GMT+02 time zone, this means the date/time returned by `toISOString` is two hours "earlier" than the local time. In some cases this can be a time before midnight, and this can render a different date as well.

The implementation of the `toJSON` method depends on `toISOString`, so it has the same behaviour.

#### Work-around

You could use [`toLocaleDateString('se')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), which uses your local time, and formats according to Swedish standards, i.e. YYYY-MM-DD, so you don't even need to slice it. There are some other country codes you could specify to have the same.